# Transition: Element is no longer attached to DOM. Unable to animate. slide down out http://localhost:8080/js/semantic.min.js?1464716916849

Tags: angular, semantic-ui

In an Angular2 template, I am using the Semantics  controls. It is working well but in dev tools console it is showing error messages like this:

```
Transition: Element is no longer attached to DOM. Unable to animate. 
slide down out http://localhost:8080/js/semantic.min.js1464716916849
```

What does this error message mean?

Comment: Your element is removed from DOM by using structural directive such as ngIf so the trigger click event on document cannot find that

Comment: One way is restart it to init state like if dropdown is slidedown, slideup then process anything else, visit this link to know how integrate between directive and component 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438486/calling-function-in-directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, using semantic-ui-less with Angular 4.
I found an answer here [Transition: Element is no longer attached to DOM. Unable to animate.](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3960#issuecomment-214146517)

In `theme.config` just set `@transition : 'default'` worked for me

Comment: For me ensuring I loaded the semantic transition css fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you load the semantic transition.css file.

Answer (score 0):

Got stucked at the same place. In my case I use webpack to build semantic UI parts in a bundle from `semantic-ui-less` npm package.
If you use webpack or other bundler, make sure you have 'transition' module both in less and js dependencies included.

Comment: Does it fix the issue?